# Kivy HELP: Widget and Screen manager

Tags: python, widget, screen, kivy

So I'm creating an app, and i need to have this thing:

**Widget 1:**
 - GridLayout with data from a JSON file, each data row goes to a button, so basically when you click on the button a popup box shows up. 
 - Popup: This one contains a numeric keyboard to input a password, and then you click on a button to enter on the main widget

**Main Widget:**
 - This one reads data from a JSON file and then puts it on the grid layout, just like on the widget 1

I can do the widgets just fine, in python, not in kv language, and I just cant do a thing: change from widget 1 to main widget... Please help me, i'm stuck with this thing for a long long time...

Comment: Welcome to SO Pedro. Your question is much more likely to get answers if you post some example code of what you've already tried.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with the JSONs. I gave you an example of how to change from `Screen` 1 to `Screen` 2. Maybe your problem is that you are using any other `Widget` rather than `Widget`. The `ScreenManager` just accepts `Screen` widgets.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change between screens you just need to use the `current` property. Basically you have to tell the ScreenManager which is the current screen but first you have to put a  a name on them. Here you have an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Phone>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The first screen'
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The second screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 2'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen2'""")

class Phone(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Phone()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The line

```
on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
```

will tell the screen manager to change the screen named 'screen1' with this other line

```
name: 'screen1'
```

Comment: Nice answer! I'm not the OP, but this was useful to me.